# c# - ICodeCompiler, dynamic code and statics

Tags: c#, static, compilation

I have a system that compiles and executes c# code "on the fly", so to speak.  Static classes are used holding config data within the system.

If I access a static class from within the "on the fly compiled code" - all OK.

However, If I access a static class from within the "on the fly compiled code" then try to access the same static class outside of the  "on the fly compiled code", all config data in the static class has been lost.   Almost like it has been reinstanciated.

The "on the fly compiled code" is run in the same app domain, if this makes a difference.

Can anyone explain why this occurs?  (Accessing a static from within the compiled code resets its config data)

Best,

Benny

Comment: the defalut configuration comes from what ever is excuting the code so does the on the fly run as part of some other application

Comment: Is the static class compiled with  "on the fly compiled code" ?

Comment: #rerun:   The code is executed as part of another application.  It's to allow custimisations on a system basis - like a plugin.

Comment: #jgauffin  The static class is already compiled, and just referenced by the "on the fly" code

Answer (score 0):

static in C# is not the same as static in C code.

I think you want a singleton.

```
    public sealed class Clazz
    {
        private readonly static Clazz _instance = new Clazz();

        public static Clazz Instance  { get { return _instance; } }

        static Clazz { /* Required for lazy init */ }

        private Clazz()
        {
            // implementation here
        }
    }
```

It guarantees that there is one instance of the class, ever, in an AppDomain.

If you are loading your dynamically-compiled code in a distinct AppDomain, and you want a cross-appdomain singleton, there are solutions for that too (Google is your friend).

Comment: Does this mean that the static was re-initialised when it was accessed from within the "on the fly" code? Anyhow- thank you for the time, I will try the above and feedback my results. Thank you cheeso!